# how to embed a custom map from google maps into an app

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, customization

I created a custom map using Google Maps that has highlighted features of the local waterways around my boat company. The map is set to be shared publicly and can be found here: https://www.google.com/maps/@28.1159901,-80.5874005,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!6m1!1sztQRD4WV85yk.kzRrtK6ZMD3E
My question is can I embed this map on an app that I am developing through Como Mobile App Creator? The app already has a map page powered by Google maps but it just shows the location of the company on a standard Google map; I want to embed the custom map I created so that it shows up in the app.
     The Como App Maker also features a custom page wherein you can add source code, and I got the source code from Google maps and tried to add it in there but the custom page just shows up blank in the app. Here is the source code I used: iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/embed?mid=ztQRD4WV85yk.kzRrtK6ZMD3E"width="640" height="480"

How do I embed my custom map on the app I am making?

Comment: Your code didn't get posted. Please edit your post and add it.

Comment: Sorry I don't know why the code didn't post; I had to take out the <iframe in the beginning and the ></iframe> at the end

Answer (score 0):

One reason I can see is: mapsengine is deprecated and new mapsengine projects are not accepted anymore.

Potential solution steps:
1) Use [My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/) instead of Maps Engine.
2) Create custom map by importing your map layer there.
3) Save that map and go to share. Make it public (pick & choose view only or can edit).
4) Click on options (drop down) menu on the right of where "Add Layer" and "Share" are and choose "[Embed on my site](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/4708605?hl=en)". You will be provided with an iframe.

This will embed that custom map you just created in your app.

Few things to keep in mind:
My Maps are ideal only for
1) Less than 2500 map views per day.
2) The data in the map does not change very frequently.
3) However, the embedded map will reflect the changes (if any) made (by you or people who has edit permissions) to the map in My Maps.

**EDIT**:
I'm sorry I did not check the URL before. So I went to it now and loaded it in My Maps. I got this iframe. See snippet.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=ztQRD4WV85yk.kzRrtK6ZMD3E&hl=en" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

But I would still encourage to make it in My Maps if this one was made in mapsengine so it is still there after mapsengine is stopped altogether in January 2016 (see Deprecation notice [here](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/)).

Hope this helped.